# Linq where in between IENumerable and List<>

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have filled `List<Object1>` Object 1 contain 2 fields (int id & string name)

Also i Have `IEnumerable<Object2>` Generated by linq2sql. With fields (id, name)

i need to get items from `List<Object1>` which **Id's** are absent in `IEnumerable<Object2>`.
 by **Key Field = id**
(like where in in sql..)

i used code like

```
IEnumerable Object2
List<Object1> excepted =  Object2.Where(t => obj1.Contains == t.Id);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
HashSet<string> knownIds = new HashSet<string>(list2.Select(x => x.Id));
var exceptions = list1.Where(x => !knownIds.Contains(x.Id));
```

As Earwicker rightly says, this will just give an `IEnumerable<Object1>` - if you need a list, change the second line to:

```
var exceptions = list1.Where(x => !knownIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by the following way.

```
var excepted = objects1.Where(o1 => !objects2.Select(o2 => o2.Id).Contains(o1.Id));
```

Best Regards

Comment: I think there is a small mistake:
var excepted = objects1.Where(o => !objects2.Select(i => i.ID).Contains(o.ID));

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised nobody has suggested join:

```
var excepted = (from o1 in List1
                join o2 in List2
                  on o1.Id equals o2.Id into j
                where !j.Any() // j is empty
                select o1
                ).ToList();
```

Perhaps marginally less as efficient than Jon's HashSet solution, but query syntax is fun.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Jon Skeet's answer, you would need the `ToList()` extension method at the end of your expression, to turn it into a List.